# Order by count from SQL to QueryDSL Java

Tags: java, sql, jpa, querydsl

I have an entity called "dog" with the column type "color", which can be BROWN, BLACK or WHITE and I need to return the DECRESCENT order of predominant colors.
Example: BROWN(3 dogs)>WHITE(2 dogs)>BLACK(1 dogs)

I did this on SQL:

```
select color, count(color) from dog d group by color order by count(color) desc;
```

and returned this, exactly what I wanted

```
color |count|
------+-----+
BROWN |    3|
WHITE |    2|
BLACK |    1|
```

My goal, following the example above, is to return it on postman GET request in the order of responses: `{ browndog1}, {browndog2}, {browndog3} {whitedog1}{whitedog2}{blackdog1}`

But NOW I'm struggling to write this logic on QueryDSL, I tried this but it didn't return correctly:

```
 QdogEntity dogEntity = QdogEntity.dogEntity;
        return new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
                 .select(dogEntity)
                 .from(dogEntity)
                 .groupBy(dogEntity)
                 .orderBy(dogEntity.color.count().desc())
                 .fetch();
```

Comment: Try placing ```.groupBy```  *before* ```.orderBy```

Comment: I tried now, i did the request and returned in wrong order: WHITE, BROWN, BROWN, WHITE, BROWN, BLACK. It was weird

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't complaining on the query, but you are selecting the full entity as select(dogEntity) is not equivalent to your SQL "select color, count(color)". You'll want to work it out so it is along the Lines of JPQL "select d.color, count(d) as dogCount from DogEntity d group by d.color order by dogCount  desc". Possibly .select(dogEntity.color, dogEntity.count()).from(dogEntity).groupBy(dogEntity.color).orderBy(dogEntity.color.count().desc()).fetch();

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. My goal, following the example, is to return it on postman GET request in the order of responses: { browndog1}, {browndog2}, {browndog3} {whitedog1}{whitedog2}{blackdog1}